# Compare two large files but ignore order of lines

Tags: comparison, file-compare

I have 2 files that I need to compare, but each file has many of the same entries on different lines. How can I compare 2 LARGE files (many gb's) and only see the lines that dont show up in the other?

Example:

File1: Line 1: Hello Line 2: Goodbye Line 3: Cake

File2: Line 1: Cake Line 2: Hello Line 3: Test Line 4: Goodbye

and only Line3 would be displayed because it is different, and everything else wont

Comment: if you don't care about order, sort each then diff the sorted files.

Comment: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724786/how-to-diff-two-file-lists-and-ignoring-place-in-list)